# Rendering Highcharts using Angular js Directives

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am new to Angular JS and trying to render my highcharts (Basic Line) by creating a directive. Please tell me the approach I should follow here. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my script for the highcharts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});


    </script>
```

Comment: you can check this work https://github.com/rootux/angular-highcharts-directive

Answer (score 50):

Example of pie chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/csTzc/

```
    function MyCtrl($scope, limitToFilter) {
  $scope.ideas = [
    ['ideas1', 1],
    ['ideas2', 8],
    ['ideas3', 5]
  ];

  $scope.limitedIdeas = limitToFilter($scope.ideas, 2);
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('hcPie', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log(2);

    },
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(3);
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      scope.$watch("items", function (newValue) {
        chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
      }, true);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great, but what if you are constantly adding and removing series? Do you have to rewrite them using the HighCharts API and insert and remove series from the chart by hand within the $watch function?

Comment: It's almost perfect. Only thing I am running into is the rederTo Id part, which makes this directive unreusable.  Is there a way to pass an id in from the controller that it could bind to the template? I've been fighting with it for an hour now..

Comment: @jwimmer in general you have a template which return div with this id, but if you get rid of it, you can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/csTzc/310/

Comment: THe problem is with controller, because simple demo works well. http://jsfiddle.net/csTzc/533/

Answer (score 30):

Alternative implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Cp73s/

This uses https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

This allows you to create a highchart with the below html:

```
<highchart id="chart1" series="chart.series" title="chart.title" options="chart.options"></highchart>
```

In the above case `chart.series` is an array of javascript objects representing the series on the chart - these take standard Highcharts options. These are then watched by angularjs for any changes.

`chart.options` is the highcharts initalisation options - also watched for changes. Although changes to this recreate the entire chart.

`chart.title` is the highcharts title object - also watched for changes.

Comment: everythis is fine but jsfiddle example was not working due to the missing config , it took me a while to figure this out. correct usgae is below <highchart id="chart1" series="chart.series" title="chart.title" options="chart.options" config="chart"></highchart>

Comment: HI , how to covert this angular highchart to binary image ,can u please help ,i am getting some error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245398/how-to-convert-highchart-to-binary-image/19245522?noredirect=1#comment28488385_19245522

Comment: highcharts-ng is great, but I'm using highmaps and it looks like it's currently unsupported... :(

Comment: @ShawnStrickland, a quick look at `highcharts-ng` forks revealed two users that have added Highmaps support.. Check [here](https://github.com/dmitruk/highcharts-ng/commit/43ebc321eb7ebcd32d8de7af88eb3c5ca531ea56) and [here](https://github.com/hanneskaeufler/highcharts-ng/commit/a5182608f1eb35050aee4d628bf99807fbc97890) for more info.

Comment: Highmaps are now supported!

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.directive('hcChart', function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
   template: '<div></div>',
   scope: {
     options: '='
    },
   link: function (scope , element, attribute) {
                Highcharts.chart('chart', {
                  chartOptions: {
                         type: 'line'
                    },
                     
                     title: {
                        text: 'Temperature data'
                     },
                 series: [{
                        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                     }]
                });
   }
 }
   
});
```

```html
<div id="chart" hc-chart>Placeholder for generic chart</div>
```

Make sure highchart lib is added in your index.html