# Highcharts- Unable to change yAxis label

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to render charts using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) js-library. As I am working with AngularJS, I am using an [AngularJS directive for HighCharts](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng).

I made everything work fine but due to some weird reason, I am unable to change the yAxis label value.

I get the default value "Values" shown on the chart's y-axis, which I checked is defined in the [highcharts.js](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js) file under "defaultYAxisOptions".

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <highchart id="chart1" config="chart"></highchart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.chart = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'x-axix-label'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'y-axix-label'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },
        loading: false
    }

});
```

Sample implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/VwTCn/9/

Can someone please point out the mistake here.

Comment: Have you seen similar topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904739/rendering-highcharts-using-angular-js-directives

Comment: Yes, that post helped me to get started with Highcharts. An implementation is given by Pablojim (http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Cp73s/) where if you try to add the y-axis label, it still doesn't show up on the y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a while, to understand, that highcharts-ng doesn't work, using the original highcharts options structure.

Anyway, for some reason it works, if you put you yAxis config into the options object, like this:

```
...
options: {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'y-axis label'
        }
    }
},
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'x-axis label'
    }
},
series: [{
...
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/martinczerwi/VwTCn/13/

Comment: Thanks, it worked. There might be a bug in the AngularJS highcharts directive.

Comment: Thanks. Wish I'd found this post earlier.