# How to render charts in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, highcharts

I am new to angularjs
For my project work I need to display the data I am getting from backend in form of charts
(Pie charts,Bar graphs,column charts etc)
I googled for this,and found various websites such as highcharts,d3 but have no clue how to implement them in angularjs.
Are there any tutorials for this?
How to get charts working in angularjs?
I am newbie to angular and completely new to charts.Never worked on them before.
Can someone guide on how to strat with charts and how to integrate them with angularjs?

Comment: Related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904739/rendering-highcharts-using-angular-js-directives/15925192#15925192

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this site http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/
Since you are new to both angularJS and charts let me give you some hints (some could be really obvious).

- angular is a MVC framework
- angular scope is the application context for your model -> so you can think of M in MVC as a scope in angular
- chart is nothing else than data visualisation -> it means it is a V in the MVC
- if you want your charts to be interactive the controller is taking place. The view change only as a result of change of your model (this happens via angular controllers)

Answer (score 1):

I have a personal preference for [n3-charts](http://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/#/) and [n3-pie-charts](http://n3-charts.github.io/pie-chart/#/):

- it is easy to use
- it has great aesthetics