# Interactive charts in angularjs or highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Can any one tell me how to create a charts in angularjs or highcharts. which is having interaction with list box. means the dimensions and measures are sent through list boxes

Comment: Please show some effort, what have you tried? We are not here to do your work ;) But in the meantime, check out this awesome library: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: what have u done, where is your research??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an external directive maybe ( http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat or search or more here http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=chart ) and check the API that is providing (or maybe wrap it up in a div with some dynamic size variables).

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using wrapper [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) and or related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904739/rendering-highcharts-using-angular-js-directives/15925192#15925192)