# Using angularjs to create a function that returns Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm still fairly new to angularjs and highcharts, what i'm trying to do is instead of declaring each chart in javascript manually, i want to send a few parameters to an angularjs function and that function returns a chart object and be rendered onto the div.

When i try the code with angularjs, it doesn't work, i create the charts main and chart1 by 'hand', using the function i created to make chart2 it's not rendering.

here is just the angularjs code:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []).factory('Chart', function() {
  return {
    crearGrafica: function(chartName, percent, estado, localidad) {
      return new Highcharts.Chart({
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          plotShadow: false,
          renderTo: chartName,
          polar: true,

          type: 'line'
        },
        title: {

        },
        subtitle: {

          text: percent + '%',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          y: 40

        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {

          series: {
            states: {
              hover: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
          },
          pie: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '75%']
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: '',
          innerSize: '40%',
          data: [

            ['', indice], {
              name: 'Referencia100%',
              y: (100 - percent),
              sliced: false,
              selected: true,
              visible: true,
              color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)'

            },

          ]
        }]


      });
    }
  }
});


function chartController($scope, crearChart) {



  //not working
      chart2 = Chart.crearGrafica('chart2', 66, '', '');

    }

App.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var chartMain;
  var chart1;
  var chart2;
  var chart3;
  var chart4;

 //not working either
  chart2 = Chart.crearGrafica('chart2', 66, '', '');

});
```

here is a punkler i made, i tried to make it the most simple as posible.
http://plnkr.co/edit/lfGoc39zJhMp695fGIyO?p=preview

Comment: you need to create a directive of highcharts in angularjs

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904739/rendering-highcharts-using-angular-js-directives and https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng