# Highcharts using Directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am new to Angular and just getting used to how everything fits together. I want to display a chart through a directive. This chart will be static data so will neither be dynamically loaded nor updated, it is taken from a JSON.

I have referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904739/rendering-highcharts-using-angular-js-directives) but the main difference is that I am not loading Highcharts in the view. I am loading it globally in the .js file from my bower_components directory. This is my code:

**.js**

```
/* global Highcharts */

angular.module("fusoDataLoggerChart", [])

    .controller("fusoDataLoggerChartController", ["$http", "$scope", function($http, $scope) {
        "use strict";

         $scope.data = {
             "activities": [
                {},
                {},
                {
                    "title": "Engine speed",
                    "type": "DATA_LOGGER",
                    "result": {
                        "Engine speed": {
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 0,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "rpm",
                                        "value": 900
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 1000,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "rpm",
                                        "value": 1000
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 2000,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "rpm",
                                        "value": 2000
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Accelerator pedal position": {
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 0,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "%",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 1000,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "%",
                                        "value": 10.6
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": 2000,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "QUANTITY",
                                        "unit": "%",
                                        "value": 11
                                     }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }])

    .directive("fusoDataLoggerChart", function() {
        "use strict";

        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.dataLoggerData = scope.data["activities"][2]["result"];

                scope.timestamps     = getData()[0];
                scope.engineSpeeds   = getData()[1];
                scope.pedalPositions = getData()[2];

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line',
                        animation: false,
                        renderTo: "DataLoggerChartContainer",
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "linear",
                        title: {
                            text: "Timestamp"
                        },
                        min: 0,
                        categories: scope.timestamps
                    },
                    yAxis: [{       //Engine Speed
                        title: {
                            text: 'Engine Speed'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} RPM'
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }, {            //Accelerator Pedal Position
                        title: {
                            text: 'Accelerator Pedal Position'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} %'
                        },
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        // FIXME: 'allowDecimal' may not work
                        allowDecimal: true
                    }],
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Engine Speed',
                        type: 'spline',
                        yAxis: 1,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' RPM'
                        },
                        data: scope.engineSpeeds
                    }, {
                        name: 'Accelerator Pedal Position',
                        type: 'spline',
                        yAxis: 2,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' %'
                        },
                        data: scope.pedalPositions
                    }]
                });

                function getData() {
                    var timestamps      = [],
                        engineSpeeds    = [],
                        pedalPositions  = [];

                    var engineSpeedData = scope.dataLoggerData["Engine Speed"]["data"],
                        pedalPosData    = scope.dataLoggerData["Accelerator Pedal Position"]["data"];

                    for (var i in engineSpeedData) {
                        timestamps.push(engineSpeedData[i].timestamp);
                    }

                    for (var j in engineSpeedData) {
                        engineSpeeds.push(engineSpeedData[j].value.value);
                    }

                    for (var k in pedalPosData) {
                        pedalPositions.push(pedalPosData[k].value.value);
                    }

                    return [timestamps, engineSpeeds, pedalPositions];
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<fuso-data-logger-chart>
    <div id="DataLoggerChartContainer"></div>
</fuso-data-logger-chart>
```

When I go to where the chart is to be rendered, nothing is shown (and only the HTML code set manually is displayed with nothing inside when I check in DevTools).

**N.B:** I realize I do not need the controller yet but it is there as in future the JSON will be got from a rest call from within the controller

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that Angular is running properly?  Your directive code looks fine and so does the controller.  Any chance you could create a plunker or something?  I could troubleshoot it much easier if I could see it all together to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Also, to ensure that your directive code is actually running, try adding an ``console.log('code is running')`` in the ``link()`` function.  If that works, try adding a ``console.log(chart)`` after your chart definition to ensure that the chart is indeed being created by HighCharts. I often think the problem must be more complex but in doing this action, sometimes I discover a really simple mistake I overlooked.

Comment: I have put a few `console.log()`'s but nothing is output, which suggests to me that for some reason the directive is not being called

Comment: I created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vi6oyjHuYUQNHq1uYuT2) and even add in a `ng-app` and `ng-controller` into the html but still does not seem to work. (The highcharts might not have been loaded properly but even the `console.log()` statements should be executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. There were multiple errors but I'll leave this here so maybe someone else can find it useful:

1. Highcharts and my FusoDataLoggerChart.js were not loaded into `index.html` (`<script src="modules/readVehicleData/FusoDataLoggerChart.js"></script>`) meaning that they couldn't be seen by Angular.
2. In my directive, I was trying to access the **local** scope (`scope.data`) in the `link()` function instead of trying to access the **parent** scope in the controller where the data is set. To access the parent scope, `scope.$parent.data` worked for me (**N.B:** was only 'data' for me as that's the value I set)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer to your question, but I noticed a way you can make your HTML directive a little cleaner so that you could instead use this format:

```
<fuso-data-logger-chart></fuso-data-logger-chart>
```

You don't need the `<div id="DataLoggerChartContainer">`.  You can embed that in the directive definition as a template:

```
.directive("fusoDataLoggerChart", function() {
        "use strict";

        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div id="DataLoggerChartContainer"></div>'
            link: function(scope) {
                ... your other code ...
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I attempted that but the template was not added. I, again, think this is because the directive is not being invoked for some reason